# Bash command can't find python file in same directory

Tags: python, airflow

This is what code looks like:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

# other packages
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 9, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}
dag = DAG('scraper', schedule_interval=None, 
default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'scrape',
    dag = dag,
    bash_command = 'python E:/dag/Car_Scraper.py')
# setting dependencies
dag >> t1
```

This is directory structure : E:\dag\

Car_Scraper.py resides in the same folder. But I still get this error:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/fatima/airflow/logs/scraper/scrape/2020-04-09T13:36:29.132535+00:00/1.log
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,538] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scraper.scrape 2020-04-09T13:36:29.132535+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,557] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scraper.scrape 2020-04-09T13:36:29.132535+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,558] {taskinstance.py:866} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,558] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,559] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,580] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): scrape> on 2020-04-09T13:36:29.132535+00:00
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,610] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 6740 to run task
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,748] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: scraper.scrape 2020-04-09T13:36:29.132535+00:00 [running]> LHRLT-2364.Systemsltd.local
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,775] {bash_operator.py:82} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,782] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpFZ5Gy3/scrapeMm2Ten
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,782] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: python E:/dag/Car_Scraper.py
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,819] {bash_operator.py:122} INFO - Output:
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,855] {bash_operator.py:126} INFO - python: can't open file 'E:/dag/Car_Scraper.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,855] {bash_operator.py:130} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,872] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 134, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2020-04-09 18:37:26,876] {taskinstance.py:1151} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2020-04-09 18:37:36,504] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-04-09 18:37:36,502] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Is there any other way to run it? I have come across python operator but im sure of how to use it

Edit: I placed it in a seperate directory and changed code a bit:

```
# airflow related
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

# other packages
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 9, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}
dag = DAG('scraper', schedule_interval=None, 
default_args=default_args)

templated_command = """
cd  ..\\scripts\\
python Car_Scraper.py
"""
download = BashOperator(
   task_id='download_release',
   bash_command=templated_command,
   dag=dag)
# setting dependencies
dag >> download
```

But it is giving following results:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/fatima/airflow/logs/scraper/download_release/2020-04-09T14:56:45.487450+00:00/2.log
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,958] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scraper.download_release 2020-04-09T14:56:45.487450+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,966] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scraper.download_release 2020-04-09T14:56:45.487450+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,966] {taskinstance.py:866} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,966] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,966] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,977] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): download_release> on 2020-04-09T14:56:45.487450+00:00
[2020-04-09 19:58:24,991] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 10874 to run task
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,073] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: scraper.download_release 2020-04-09T14:56:45.487450+00:00 [running]> LHRLT-2364.Systemsltd.local
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,085] {bash_operator.py:82} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,088] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpupGsj5/download_releaseTNOufD
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,088] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: 
cd  ..\scripts\
python hello.py
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,105] {bash_operator.py:122} INFO - Output:
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,109] {bash_operator.py:126} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmpupGsj5/download_releaseTNOufD: line 3: cd: too many arguments
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,109] {bash_operator.py:130} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,119] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 134, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2020-04-09 19:58:25,120] {taskinstance.py:1170} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED.dag_id=scraper, task_id=download_release, execution_date=20200409T145645, start_date=20200409T145824, end_date=20200409T145825
[2020-04-09 19:58:34,941] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-04-09 19:58:34,940] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: Are you running bash on Windows?

Comment: yes. I am running chrome in Windows and I kickstarted airflow through ubuntu terminal